# D3.JS bar graph in Firefox cshtml

Tags: d3.js, razor, bar-chart

I am trying to put together an interactive bar chart in cshtml.
The good news is it works on every browser except for Firefox.
That being said I'd very much like to know why it is failing on Firefox when it even works on Internet Explorer.. I mean come on, the internet doesn't even work on Internet Explorer.

I have added in what I believe to be the relevant patch of code here:

```
function buildVisualization(dataSet) {           
            var barWidth = (chartWidth / dataSet.Items.length - 1) - 1;

            var bars = svg.selectAll("rect")
                          .data(dataSet.Items);

            // Build bars for each item
            // Example "rect" element: <rect x="200" y="400" width="300" height="100" style="" class="" />

            bars.enter()
               .append("rect")
                .attr("x", function (item, i) { return xScale(new Date(item.DateAsked)) } )
                .attr("y", function (item, i) { return chartHeight - yScale(item.Rate)})
                .attr("width", function (item) { return barWidth})
                .attr("height", function (item) { return yScale(item.Rate)})
               .attr("fill", "teal");

            bars.exit().remove();

            bars.transition()
                .attr("x", function (item, i) { return xScale(new Date(item.DateAsked))} )
                .attr("y", function (item, i) { return chartHeight - yScale(item.Rate)})
                .attr("width", function (item) { return barWidth})
                .attr("height", function (item) { return yScale(item.Rate)})
                .attr("fill", "teal");            
        }
```

That being said I can provide any information required if requested.

I should point out that when run the chart itself is put into the right place however the bars (an important bit of a bar chart) are all pushed off to the left and stacked on top of each other though they do change height when different options are selected so it seems to be something wrong with the positioning rather than with how they are created. Any advice would be quite welcome.

---

Entire Snippet:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Bar Chart";
    var choices = new List<SelectListItem>
    (){
new SelectListItem(){Text= "C#", Value="c#", Selected=true },
new SelectListItem(){Text= ".Net", Value=".net" },
new SelectListItem(){Text= "ASP.Net", Value="asp.net" },
new SelectListItem(){Text= "ASP.Net MVC", Value="asp.net-mvc" },
new SelectListItem(){Text= "C", Value="c" },
new SelectListItem(){Text= "C++", Value="c++" },
new SelectListItem(){Text= "JavaScript", Value="javascript" },
new SelectListItem(){Text= "Objective C", Value="objective-c" },
new SelectListItem(){Text= "PHP", Value="php" },
new SelectListItem(){Text= "Ruby", Value="ruby" },
new SelectListItem(){Text= "Python", Value="python" }
};
}
<style type="text/css">

    svg g.axis {
        font-size: .75em;
        font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    }

        svg g.axis text.label {
            font-size: 2em;
            font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        }

        svg g.axis path,
        svg g.axis line {
            fill: none;
            stroke: black;
            shape-rendering: crispEdges;
        }
</style>
<h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <p>This demo takes tag information from <a href="http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries">data.stackexchange.com</a> and projects it below.</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        @Html.Label("TagChoice", "Tag")
        @Html.DropDownList("TagChoice", choices)
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div id="chartContainer">
    </div>
</div>
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/d3")
@section Scripts{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#TagChoice").on("change", function () {
                var tag = $(this).val();
                var url = "/api/tags?tag=";
                url += encodeURIComponent(tag);

                $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
                    buildVisualization(data);
                });
            });

            $("#TagChoice").change();
        });

        // Overall dimensions of the SVG
        var height = 400;
        var width = 900;

        // Padding...
        var leftPadding = 75;
        var bottomPadding = 50;

        // Actual space for the bars
        var chartWidth = width - leftPadding;
        var chartHeight = height - bottomPadding;

        //Building the scale for the heights
        var yScale = d3.scale
            .linear()
            .range([0, chartHeight])
            .domain([0, 21000]);

        var yAxisScale = d3.scale
            .linear()
            .range([chartHeight, 0])
            .domain([0, 21000]);

        //Building the scale for the bar locations
        var xScale = d3.time.scale()
            .domain([new Date("5-1-2008"), new Date("2-1-2014")])
            .range([leftPadding, width - 10]);

        //Building a Y axis
        var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(yAxisScale)
            .orient("left");

        // Building an X Axis
        var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(xScale)
            .orient("bottom")
            .tickFormat(d3.time.format("%m/%d/%Y"));

        // Build the overall SVG container
        var svg = d3.select("#chartContainer")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height)
            .attr("class", "chart");

        // Adding the Axes
        svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "axis")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + leftPadding + ",0)")
            .call(yAxis)
            .append("text")
            .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
            .attr("dy", "-55px")
            .attr("dx", "-50px")
            .attr("class", "label")
            .style("text-anchor", "end")
            .text("Number of Questions Asked");


        svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "axis")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + chartHeight + ")")
            .call(xAxis)
            .append("text")
            .attr("dy", "40px")
            .attr("dx", "475px")
            .attr("class", "label")
            .style("text-anchor", "end")
            .text("Month Asked");


        function buildVisualization(dataSet) {
            var barWidth = (chartWidth / dataSet.Items.length - 1) - 1;

            var bars = svg.selectAll("rect")
                .data(dataSet.Items);

            // Build bars for each item
            // Example "rect" element: <rect x="200" y="400" width="300" height="100" style="" class="" />

            bars.enter()
                .append("rect")
                .attr("x", function (item, i) { return xScale(new Date(item.DateAsked)) })
                .attr("y", function (item, i) { return chartHeight - yScale(item.Rate) })
                .attr("width", function (item) { return barWidth })
                .attr("height", function (item) { return yScale(item.Rate) })
                .attr("fill", "teal");

            bars.exit().remove();

            bars.transition()
                .attr("x", function (item, i) { return xScale(new Date(item.DateAsked)) })
                .attr("y", function (item, i) { return chartHeight - yScale(item.Rate) })
                .attr("width", function (item) { return barWidth })
                .attr("height", function (item) { return yScale(item.Rate) })
                .attr("fill", "teal");
        }
    </script>
}
```

Comment: What format do you use for dates? Can you share complete snippet or give link to http://stackblitz.com?

Comment: Well the date format is mm/dd/yyyy however I don't really see how it is relevant. Let me get that snippet.. one second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the reason of your problem is that in Chrome

```
>> new Date("5-1-2008")
Thu May 01 2008 ...
```

while in Firefox:

```
>> new Date("5-1-2008")
Invalid Date
```

(this is relevant to lines, where you construct `xScale`)

Comment: Yeah, fixed the issue by changing '5-1-2008' to '5/1/2008' this format is supported across most of the browsers I tested on.